# Magento. Содержимое страниц, созданных в CMS.

Tags: magento, cms

CMS Magento. Создаю страницу в админке CMS->Pages. Можно ли содержимое созданной таким образом страницы отобразить, например, на главной?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, для этого даже существует стандартная страница CMS -> Pages -> Home Page.
Посмотрите примеры её использования, установив Magento с демо-данными.